# Business rules as REST API or module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, business-rules

I m building an application that contains :

- A front end angularjs
- A backend express application

The fact is that both are using the same business rules for validation, one time in front end, and the other, on the back part to maintain a good navigability (locking in front) and good business management (locking in back).

This way, I was wondering about a way to manage my business rules for both sides in one place.

This way, I've found two solutions :

**- Create a npm module**

*PROS :* This could work with versionning, accessible from both client and back side due to the javascript technology

*CONST :* Only available for javascript, and if I need, in the future, to add a new technology, I would have to make it for the technology concerned. There's also the fact that I have to make a remote request, and use the network. Exactly what I don't want to do with my client

**- Create a REST API exposing only my business rules**

*PROS :* accessible from both client and back side, from any technology

*CONST :* network latency, and need to manage another service from my client side

I was wondering what could be a good solution and why ?